# How to call Kotlin companion object function using reflection and interface

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

Assume I have the following interface:

```kotlin
interface Fooable {
    fun foo()
}
```

The interface is implemented by named companion objects; for example:

```kotlin
class Impl1 {
    companion object Foo : Fooable {
        fun foo() { ... }
    }
}

class Impl2 {
    companion object Foo : Fooable {
        fun foo() { ... }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to map the name of each *Impl* class to a `Fooable` instance (since companion objects are always singleton instances); for example:

```kotlin
fun mapImplToFooable(): Map<String, Fooable> = mapOf(
    "Impl1" to Impl1.Foo,
    "Impl2" to Impl2.Foo
)
```

I could then call this; for example:

```kotlin
val map = mapImplToFooable()
map["Impl1"]!!.foo()
```

What I want is to be able to create the map using reflection, rather than hard coding it, assuming convention being that every *Impl* has a `companion object Foo : Fooable { ... }`

What I have so far is a function which is able to find all classes in a package, and sub-packages:

```kotlin
fun findAllClasses(): List<Class<*>> { ... }
```

And from that, I managed to get this far:

```kotlin
function mapImplToFooable(): Map<String, Fooable> {
    return findAllClasses()
        .filter { Fooable::class.java.isAssignableFrom(it) }
        .map { clazz -> it.name to clazz } // This is a problem...
        .toMap()
```

The problem is that `clazz` is a `Class<Fooable>` rather than an instance of `Fooable` (in each case, the companion object).

How do I obtain the companion object instance, rather than just a `Class<Fooable>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Kotlin reflection API (rather than the Java one), so that you have access to [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html):

```
fun mapImplToFooable(): Map<String, Fooable> =
    findAllClasses()
        .filter { 
            Fooable::class.java.isAssignableFrom(it) &&
            it != Fooable::class.java // you should also check this if findAllClasses can return Fooable
        }
        .associate { // .map { ... }.toMap() can be simplified to associate
            // you should get the declaring class's name here
            clazz -> clazz.declaringClass.name to clazz.kotlin.objectInstance as Fooable 
        }
```